# Allow user to click a button only when email is valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-class

I am using `angularjs` on a web application. I am trying to perform something quite simple. I have an email `input` and a `button`. I only want the button's function to be enabled once a valid email is entered. I've tried:

```
<div>
    <p class="required">*</p>
    <input type="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
</div>

<div class="btn-container" ng-class={true : 'validEmail', false : 'invalidEmail'}[email]>
    <div class="btn-go" ng-click="findUser();">Go!</div>
</div>
```

Be default, i'd like the button to be blue. But once a valid email is entered, then the button turns Green. Hence the:

```
ng-class={true : 'validEmail', false : 'invalidEmail'}[email]
```

Comment: Use `<button>` and `ng-disabled` for the button.

Comment: @valverde93 - thanks, but how do you link the ng-disabled to the email field validation??

Comment: I'll post example in a few minutes

Comment: Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m81d7h5p/1)

Comment: Remember that you need quotes around your ternary operator, or it won't work, so `ng-class={true : 'validEmail', false : 'invalidEmail'}[email]` should be `"ng-class={true : 'validEmail', false : 'invalidEmail'}[email]"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
 ng-class="myForm.input.$valid ? 'valid' : 'invalid'"
```

`ng-class` checks whether the input is valid or invalid and returns two corresponding classes for `.valid` and `.invalid`.

While then you can apply styles with **CSS**:

```
.valid {
  background: green;
}

.invalid {
  background: blue;
}
```

The **HTML** should be something like this:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Email:
    <input type="email" name="input" ng-model="email.text" required>
  </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
        Required!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.email">
        Not valid email!</span>
  </div>
  <tt>text = {{email.text}}</tt>
  <br/>
  <button ng-class="myForm.input.$valid ? 'valid' : 'invalid'">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In **controller**:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.email = {
    text: 'me@example.com'
  };
}]);
```

Also you can use `ng-disabled="myForm.input.$invalid"` on the button to make it unusable if the input is invalid.

See an **[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NZ2HSx6sadQ172qR5mQe?p=preview)**.

**Resources**: *[input[email]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D), [The many ways to use ngClass](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass), [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)*.